# How to make label position fixed in dynamic values?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I want to show following results in aspx page.The value in () came from db which cab be any value or may be zero.

```
Team1 (324.56S + 23R) => 257.56
Team2 (12S + 23R)     => 55
Team3 (15S + 3R)      => 18
Team3 (0S + 0R)       => 0
```

but the problem is that the position of => depends upon the previous values.How to achieve the required results and make them fixed for what ever the value in ().

Mine code is

```
<asp:Label ID="lblTeam1" runat="server" Style="margin-left: 50px" Font-Size="X-Small"
                                        Font-Names="Verdana"></asp:Label>                                   
<asp:Label ID="lblTeam2" runat="server" Style="margin-left: 718px" Font-Size="X-Small"
                                        Font-Names="Verdana"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="lblTeam3" runat="server" Style="margin-left: 720px" Font-Size="X-Small"
                                        Font-Names="Verdana"></asp:Label>
```

but the result is

```
Team1 (324.56S + 23R) => 257.56
Team2 (12S + 23R) => 257.56
Team3 (15S + 3R)   => 16.56
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm trying to get a semantic and pure CSS approach for this (I believe that in this HTML, the rows should be together, not the left and right columns), but for now, doing a HTML table is pretty quick an easy.

Preview: http://jsfiddle.net/8Qy2p/

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Team1 (324.56S + 23R)</td>
        <td>=> 257.56</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Team2 (12S + 23R)</td>
        <td>=> 55</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Team3 (15S + 3R)</td>
        <td>=> 18</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Team3 (0S + 0R)</td>
        <td>=> 0</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```